# NetInfo.addEventListener is calling multiple times when network changes online/offline

Tags: react-native

It should call only once. When NetInfo.addEventListener calls it call three times. I want to call it once.

```
NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {

        props.connectionState(state.isConnected)

        NetInfo.addEventListener('connectionChange', state => {

            props.connectionState(state.isConnected)

            AsyncStorage.getItem('responseData').then(data => {

                if (data !== null) {
                    let response = JSON.parse(data)
                    console.log('length', response.length)
                    response.forEach(element => {
                        props.submitDataOffline(element)
                    });

                }

            });

        });

    });
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: NetInfo.addEventListener should call only once.

Comment: you should call .addEventListener only once, but this piece of code is clearly inside of component, and will keep adding new listeners every time this code runs

Answer (score 0):

You need to unsubscribe each of your subscribed listeners. Otherwise they will accumulate as you load the view.

```
// component methods to register networkInfo
componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(this.connectionChange);
}

// component methods to unregister networkInfo and appState listener
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
}
```

So I would rewrite your code as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
  NetInfo.fetch().then(state => props.connectionState(state.isConnected)});

  this.unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener('connectionChange', state => {
       props.connectionState(state.isConnected)

       AsyncStorage.getItem('responseData').then(data => {
                if (data !== null) {
                    let response = JSON.parse(data)
                    console.log('length', response.length)
                    response.forEach(element => {
                        props.submitDataOffline(element)
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribe
    let currentState

    // Subscribe NetInfo event
    unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
      if (currentState !== state.isConnected) {
        currentState = state.isConnected
        console.log("Is connected?", currentState);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      console.log("unsubscribe");

      if (unsubscribe)
        unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: You can use the fetch method instead, I tried both, it's the same result.
https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo#usage

Answer (score 0):

in my case

I have handled this through closers and global variable

```
   let startApi = false; // global
   
   class App extends React.Component .....
   ..........

    async componentDidMount() {
      NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
      console.log('Connection type', state. Type);
      console.log('Is connected?', state.isConnected);
      var callOnlyOnce = (function() {
      return function() {
       if (startApi) {
         startApi = false;
         alert('hello');
       }
    };
   })();

     if (state.isConnected === true) {
       callOnlyOnce();
       startApi = true;
     } else {
       startApi = true;
       callOnlyOnce();
     }
   });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid multiple calls from the NetInfo listener, I created a state (isOnline). Whenever that state changes with setIsOnline(state.isConnected), the useEffect is triggered only when the status changes from true to false or vice versa. You can place your code in that useEffect to run only once when you disconnect or connect.

```
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Subscribe
    const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
      setIsOnline(state.isConnected);
      
    });

    return () => {
      // Unsubscribe
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({isOnline});

    //Do code that runs once the connection changes
  }, [isOnline]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please Add Some details so user can understand it clearly.